# outlook.office.com - 500 Something went wrong. Repeating redirects detected

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

When I try to log in to Outlook I get the current message:

> 500 Something went wrong. Repeating redirects detected.

[image]

Then:

> We couldn't sign you in. Please try again.

[image]

Tried with different browsers, incognito and even on a iPad that has never logged in with the business email. Same result every time.

Everything works except for email login. I can for example log in to the admin console. I have tried to remove every alias and check other settings but it does not work. It works for my colleagues, only my email is affected.

Answer (score 15):

Turned out to be too many roles:

[image]

Changed so I only had `Global Administrator` role via another Admin account and then everything started working.

Comment: +1 for sharing. Interesting problem I haven't seen before.

Comment: @LPChip Thank you! No I could not find anything about it either so therefore I decided to share it.

Comment: My first guess would have been that outlook itself has been disabled (that is called web app under user, email, services). Its possible this is still the case, but that Global admin rights bypass this restriction.

Comment: @LPChip My user was `Global Administrator` the whole time with a `Microsoft 365 Business premium` license. Spoke to Microsoft support and apparently the error can occur if you have too many roles. In our case it only happened after we did a DNS change for our main domain. My colleagues accounts started working but mine did not.

Comment: Ah, good to know. :)